# Laravel Blade template with Vue js components and Googlebot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade, vue-component

everyone!
I have a problem with rendering my project for Googlebot. My team and I make a store on laravel and VueJS 2, this is online store and SEO will be very important for this project. But Googlebot can't render our site ([our site](http://for-men.ua/),[pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffor-men.ua%2F&tab=mobile)). 
We combine Blade template and Vue components.

Does anyone know how to help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the best way for SEO optimize is let node do ssr https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html, router and laravel just become api endpoint but there is a github project on Server-Side Rendering with PHP V8Js. i dont know how it works though, check https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4101